# Products with same value from Metafield link Shopify

Tags: metadata, shopify, meta

I'm relatively new with Shopify/liquid and I have this site - https://grapevinestore.myshopify.com/collections/frontpage/products/test-product

Where I've got metafields and values on products coming in using this code

```
{% if product.metafields.producer_new.producer_new %}<strong>Producer: </strong> {{ product.metafields.producer_new.producer_new }}{% endif %}
```

My Question is just more of an is it possible, as I can't find anything about it in documenttation..

Would it be possible to turn the value, in this case the producer value 'nfdijfivbdf' into a link, so if linked, other products with the value of 'nfdijfivbdf' in their producer metafield would show?

Hopefully this makes sense, any advice would be much appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: So you like to show all the products with the same metafield. Is this correct? Short answer is you can't. Long answer you can but you will be limited to 50 products request, because of the Shopify set limit.

Comment: Create a collection with 'nfdijfivbdf' and provide the link to that collection. Better way would be to use the vendor field for this purpose and change the word "vendor" to producer on the website

Comment: @HymnZ The vendor idea would be great, but I need it for all those custom fields I've created

Comment: @drip Yes that's correct, so if say the Alc/Vol field had a percentage of 14%, I'd like to be able to click on 14% and be taken to all other products that are 14%.. Not sure if this is even possible as I am new to Shopify as a platform but any points in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Comment: @LucyBrown, you can do it for any field you require. For your 14% case, create a collection with a rule to match the tag `14%`, for a "vendor" create a collection to match the vendor to your `producer`

Comment: @HymnZ Ok, but would I be able to do it for multiple fields for each product? If you look at the link you'll see theres a few custom fields and as far as i know there's only one vendor field, I hope this makes sense!

Comment: @LucyBrown .. The page is locked with a password.

Comment: @HymnZ Sorry! Password is "blowch"

Comment: It can be done. And that too wonderfully for UX/UI and SEO purposes. All you have to do is tag the product with all the things you have mentioned (except for producer.. it's best suited as a vendor) and create metafields as well. Then for each property create a collection using tag as the selector. (ex tag is "nkvd"). Even more you can use it for structured data as well.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help!